# Denying load of font-awesome resources in my Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing an extension using a content script, but Chrome won't load my font-awesome resources, giving me the error message about how I need to add them to web_accessible_resources in my manifest, but I have already.

My CSS looks as follows:

```
font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.5.0');
  src: url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.5.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.5.0') format('woff2'), url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.5.0') format('woff'), url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.5.0') format('truetype'), url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.5.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

And in my manifest file, I've tried several combinations, such as:

```
"web_accessible_resources": ["fontawesome-webfont.woff2", "/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2", "*.woff2","fonts/*", "/fonts/*", "/fonts/*.woff2"]
```

I've left out other resources for brevity, but the idea is that I've tried multiple paths, combinations, wildcards, etc.

But when my script is activated, Chrome reports:

> "Denying load of
>   chrome-extension://xxx/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.5.0.
>   Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key
>   in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension."

My file structure in the extension is the CSS is in the root and all of the font files are in the /fonts directory below that.

Answer (score 2):

So I solved my own problem, but just in case someone else has the same problem, I'll post it here. The issue was my manifest file. I had the "web_accessible_resources" declared under "content_scripts" instead of as a root node. So in the end, the error message it was giving me was valid and just a case of RTFM.